# How to access files at path /var/containers/Bundle/Application/ABCDCS54-DACA-DAD/MyApp.app/AppData/models XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsbundle

I am working on existing project trying to add new features to an iOS app. I have models inside my app but I do not know where those models are stored inside XCode. Console log shows that files are stored at path

> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/ABCDCS54-DACA-DAD/MyApp.app/AppData/models

```
- (NSString*)applicationDataDirectory
{
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppData"];
}
```

I checked every folder and almost every file to find any clue where are those models. No success. I spent several days trying to figure out. Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you path is device memory location, if you want to check models then you need to run in simulator and then check you path and open in you machine

Comment: I thought about that but anyway if I run the app for the first time then it means app saves all those files in phone memory. I want to know how it does that. There is no piece of code that shows app is storing any files.